# WARNING. Duplicate resource in Delphi 7, Infopower 4000

Tags: delphi, compilation, delphi-7

[Error] WARNING. Duplicate resource(s):
[Error] Type  2 (BITMAP), ID TWWDBRICHEDITMSWORD:
[Error] File C:\Borland\Delphi7\ip4000vcl7\LIB\wwrichsp.RES resource kept; 
           file C:\Borland\Delphi7\ip4000vcl7\LIB\wwrichsp.RES resource discarded.
I have searched the code for same named objects, like objects.
Can anyone give me a clue what else I can look for.

Answer (score 4):

Two units both using the same resource file. Probably looks like this:

```
{$R wwrichsp.RES}
```

Answer (score 0):

wwrichedspellxp,  wwrichedspell2000; 这两个同时存在时就出错。Delete wwrichedspellxp 就OK